# How to view the result of an expression in MSVS2013?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, mfc

I remember seeing somewhere that you can specify which dll to get the address of symbols so that one can use that variable in the watch window.  I can't for the life of me remember where I saw this.  The best that I can come up with is [Format Specifiers in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx).

The reason I want this is so that I can see the visibility status of a window and MSVS keeps saying that `identifier "IsWindowVisible" is undefined`.

I was trying to use something like the following in the watch window:

```
::IsWindowVisible(m_hWnd),user32.dll
```

Using:

```
this->IsWindowVisible()
```

results in `Function CWnd::IsWindowVisible has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations.` which is why I'm trying to use the win32 call.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/y2t7ahxk.aspx

Haven't tried it, but it seems to me that IsWindowVisible(m_hWnd) should work, or maybe IsWindowVisible(this->m_hWnd).

Comment: That is basically what I stated that I tried in the question.

Comment: No, you stated other variations. One of them should work, according to the documentation. Either way, the link I gave points to the documentation you were asking about.